# What should I take in consideration when planning a Design Science Research?

Tags: thesis, methodology

I am planning a proposal for a thesis (on Forecasting Daily Energy Prices), in which I need to select the methodology and define its phases.

As I intend to develop new technologies and/or solve specific problems, I was investigating the most adequate, when I came across the article *Design Science Research Methodology for Information Systems Research* ([read it here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f434/877eafb05eb24e49a10633e1fae2ef18bedf.pdf)).

In that article one can read about investigation process **Design Science Research** (DSR) and its steps, and it seems appropriate for what I intend to do.

Assuming that DSR will be the methodology for my investigation, what should I take in consideration when creating the plan/defining the phases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Talk to your advisor to determine if an artefact-oriented approach is the correct approach for your research questions.

Generally, there are three general approaches to research that different research methodologies can fall into: quantitative/scientific, qualitative/descriptive, and artefact-oriented. In the first you’re dealing with numerical data that you can statistically analyse to prove or disprove hypotheses; in the second, you’re dealing with descriptive information that you can classify and analyse with techniques like coding. With artefact-oriented research, you’re designing a system that you then evaluate compared to the state of the art.

One important consideration for artefact-oriented research is that there needs to be a production of new knowledge that is separated from the artefacts you produce; if you take away all of the datasets and computer systems, if there isn’t anything left, you haven’t been doing research, you’ve been doing development.

Comment: would you be able to give an example of new knowledge that is separate from the artefacts? Thank you.